# OpenLayers.Map is not a constructor

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am trying to enter in my maps application (GeoServer, PostGIS, OpenLayers) but it is empty and I get an error with Firebug: `TypeError: OpenLayers.Map is not a constructor` in my map.js script in line:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    projection: "EPSG:900913",
    displayProjection: "EPSG:4326",
    numZoomLevels: 7});`
```

What is wrong?

EDIT:
This is my header html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/examples/shared/examples.css" />
<script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./script/GeoExt.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/dev/theme/default/google.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
```

The problem occurred suddenly while I looking the layers before added. I clicked in option `Reload feature type` in a particular layer page, Could this have something to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OpenLayers.Map is not a constructor
```

is related to the OpenLayers.js file, so this is saying that this file is not located in your script tag (ie. in the HEAD section of your HTML). Also, it could be that

`<script src="http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js"></script>`

no longer works or there are some problems nowadays with it, this is because the [examples of the openlayers examples link](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) don't work now. Try instead

`<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/2.11/OpenLayers.js"></script>`

and post here what you get.

Hope this helps,

Comment: If the file is not located in the script tag the message error would be `OpenLayers.Map is not defined`, I guess. Please, see my edit.

Comment: I edited my answer, please see if that helps you. If it does, consider upvoting it and marking as the answer.